# WooCommerce Query to return list of products and total orders placed for each product

Tags: mysql, woocommerce

I am trying to get a list of all my WooCommerce products with the number of orders placed for them in the last year.

I tried to do this inside PHP, but was not successful as the "wc_get_orders" function does not offer such functionality.

So, I am trying in MySQL and have tried the following. In theory, it does work, but it takes a ridiculously long time to run.

I have 623 Products
(Ideally, I would also like to get a Total Sales Value along side the Total Order Count, but that is not as important)

Can someone help? If someone has a PHP solution I am open to that as well

```
SELECT   posts.ID AS prodID, 
(
    SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT  order_items.order_id)
        FROM woocommerce_order_items as order_items
        LEFT JOIN woocommerce_order_itemmeta as order_item_meta ON order_items.order_item_id = order_item_meta.order_item_id
        LEFT JOIN posts AS posts ON order_items.order_id = posts.ID
        WHERE posts.post_type = 'shop_order' AND posts.post_date >= curdate() - interval 1 YEAR 
        AND order_items.order_item_type = 'line_item'
        AND order_item_meta.meta_key = '_product_id'
        AND (posts.post_status = 'wc-delivered' OR posts.post_status = 'wc-completed')
        AND order_item_meta.meta_value = prodID
)
            FROM posts  INNER JOIN postmeta ON ( posts.ID = postmeta.post_id )  INNER JOIN postmeta AS mt1 ON ( posts.ID = mt1.post_id )
            WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  postmeta.meta_key = '_price' 
--  AND   ( mt1.meta_key = 'availibility' AND mt1.meta_value = 'Available' )
) AND posts.post_type = 'product' AND ((posts.post_status = 'publish'))
            GROUP BY posts.ID
            ORDER BY posts.post_date DESC
```

I have the following running in PHP which gives me my list of Products, but when I try to run a query on each iteration for the number of Orders, that is also very slow:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product', // Replace 'product' with the actual post type name of your products
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // Retrieve all posts
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'fields' => 'ids', // Retrieve only post IDs for performance optimization
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => '_price', // Replace '_price' with the actual meta key for price
            'compare' => 'EXISTS' // Make sure the price meta exists
        )
    )
);


$products = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: From what I see, this plugin only handles the wp tables, but misses the Woo order items tables. How would I handle those ones?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables involved in the query

Answer (score 0):

How long is a *"ridiculously long time to run"*? Have you used a plugin like [Index WP MySQL For Speed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/) to add indices to the database?

I would have added this as a comment, as opposed to an answer, but it is a bit too big. Try the following query to see if it performs any better:

```sql
SELECT pr.ID AS prodID, IFNULL(po.num_orders, 0) AS num_orders
FROM posts pr -- pr for product
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT oim.meta_value AS product_id, COUNT(o.ID) AS num_orders
    FROM posts o -- o for order
    JOIN woocommerce_order_items oi
        ON o.ID = oi.order_id
        AND oi.order_item_type = 'line_item'
    JOIN woocommerce_order_itemmeta oim
        ON oi.order_item_id = oim.order_item_id
        AND oim.meta_key = '_product_id'
    WHERE o.post_type = 'shop_order'
    AND o.post_date >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR 
    AND o.post_status IN ('wc-delivered', 'wc-completed')
    GROUP BY oim.meta_value
) po /* po for product_orders */ ON pr.ID = po.product_id
WHERE pr.post_type = 'product'
AND pr.post_status = 'publish'
-- AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM postmeta WHERE post_id = pr.ID AND meta_key = 'availibility' AND meta_value = 'Available')
ORDER BY pr.post_date DESC;
```

You should get better performance querying `wc_order_*` tables instead of the `woocommerce_order_*` and `posts` tables. You could try something like:

```sql
SELECT
    pr.ID AS prodID,
    IFNULL(po.num_orders, 0) AS num_orders,
    IFNULL(po.total_units, 0) AS total_units,
    IFNULL(po.total_net, 0) AS total_net,
    IFNULL(po.total_gross, 0) AS total_gross
FROM posts pr
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        op.product_id,
        COUNT(op.order_id) AS num_orders,
        SUM(op.product_qty) AS total_units,
        SUM(op.product_net_revenue) AS total_net,
        SUM(op.product_gross_revenue) AS total_gross
    FROM wc_order_stats o
    JOIN wc_order_product_lookup op
        ON o.order_id = op.order_id
    WHERE o.date_completed >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR 
    AND o.status IN ('wc-delivered', 'wc-completed')
    GROUP BY op.product_id
) po
    ON pr.ID = po.product_id
WHERE pr.post_type = 'product'
AND pr.post_status = 'publish'
-- AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM postmeta WHERE post_id = pr.ID AND meta_key = 'availibility' AND meta_value = 'Available')
ORDER BY pr.post_date DESC;
```

If this is no better, please update your question with the [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html#explain-execution-plan) output for these queries and your query.

Comment: That looks like the "explode-implode" pattern.  Start with a derived table that finds the desired pr.IDs.  Then JOIN to the other tables.  This should eliminate the need for the GROUP BY.

Comment: This took 9 minutes and 40 seconds. Also, you removed records with 0 orders (I need those too)

Comment: @user1191247 I have looked at the plugin, but not installed it. I don't understand how to use it